# django-import-export fora do Admin

Tags: django

Alguém sabe como eu faria pra usar o [django-import-export](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export) fora do Admin?
Ou seja, eu queria o botão de exportar dessa biblioteca num template meu, fora do Admin.
Qual o caminho das pedras?

Eu tentei

Estou tentando exportar tabelas para Excel usando [django-import-export](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export) fora do Admin, ou seja, num template. Vejam que em /person/ tem um botão para exportar. Dessa vez criei um [projetinho](https://github.com/rg3915/dj-export) só pra isso.

Dai vejam meu último commit

https://github.com/rg3915/dj-export/commit/43d7a8cdc719c78a5b83bf91eaed1d635c48ce6a

```
from import_export.admin import ExportMixin

def export_data_person(request):
    e = ExportMixin()
    file_format = 'XLSX'
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    return e.get_export_data(file_format, queryset)
```

E quando cliquei no botão deu o seguinte erro:

```
AttributeError at /person/export/
'ExportMixin' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Como faço pra resolver esse problema?

Estou conseguindo evoluir na solução

```
def export_data_person(request):
    e = ExportMixin()
    e.model = Person
    file_format = XLSX()
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    return e.get_export_data(file_format, queryset)
```

mas ainda falta converter os bytes para fazer o download, pois deu o seguinte erro:

```
AttributeError at /person/export/
'bytes' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido:

```
def export_data_person(request):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    return _export_data(queryset, 'person')


def export_data_person_blocked(request):
    queryset = Person.objects.filter(blocked=True)
    return _export_data(queryset, 'person-blocked')


def _export_data(queryset, filename_prefix):
    e = ExportMixin()
    e.resource_class = PersonResource
    e.model = Person
    data = e.get_export_data(XLSX(), queryset)
    mdata = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    response = HttpResponse(
        data, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response[
        'Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{0}-{1}.xlsx"'.format(filename_prefix, mdata)
return response
```